# regex to remove bootstrap column classes? Using sublime text

Tags: regex, twitter-bootstrap, sublimetext2

Trying to find and delete all classes in a theme structured like `col-md-12` or `col-sm-3`.

I thought `col-*-*` would work and replacing it with '' would delete it. But it only removes the end leaving `md-6`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `col-*-*` removes `col` followed by 0+ hyphens followed with 0+ hyphens.

You can use

```
\bcol-\w+-\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yH7sI3/1)

*Explanation:*

- `\bcol` - whole word `col` (`\b` is a word boundary used so as not to match `somecol`)
- `-` - a literal hyphen
- `\w+` - followed with 1+ alphanumeric or underscore characters
  -`-` - a hyphen
- `\d+` - 1+ digits (note: you can append `\b` so as not to match digits that not followed with non-word characters, e.g. `123bv`).